# How to make a sql search query more powerful?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I wrote this sql query to search in a table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Name LIKE '%spa%'
```

The table contain these row for example:

1. Space Company.
2. Spa resort.
3. Spa hotel.
4. Spare Parts.
5. WithoutTheKeyword.

I want to know how to edit this query so it return the results sorted like this:

> 2 Spa resort
>
> 3 Spa hotel
>
> 1 Space Company
>
> 4 Spare Parts

Means the items which contain the exact word first then the like ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

something like

```
Select * from TableName where Name Like 'Spa%'
ORDER BY case when soundex(name) = soundex('Spa') then '1' else soundex(name) end
```

should work ok.

actually this will work better

```
Select * from TableName where Name Like 'Spa%'
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(name, 'Spa') desc;
```

FWIW I did some quick tests and if 'Name' is in a NONCLUSTERED INDEX SQL will use the index and doesn't do a table scan. Also, LIKE seems to use less resources than charindex (which returns less desirable results). Tested on sql 2000.

Comment: you write "soundex(name) = soundex('Spa')", in soundex(name) whats the name equal or should i wrote i like this?

Comment: for the first script you wrote, it always give me this error:"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'L000' to data type int."

Comment: But you fundamentally changed the question by removing the leading wildcard.

Comment: Perhaps, I thought is was superfluous. amrelgarhy? I will see if that makes a diff when I get a chance. But still, your answer while perhaps not incorrect could have been phrased in a less condescending tone or even more helpful. I's just trying to defend the new guy.

Comment: You're inferring something I didn't intend to imply. I was trying to give the benefit of the doubt rather than "it's obvious you don't even realize ..." Other responses seem to say that at least a few others read it that way. Although it's always a good reminder to try harder.

Comment: ok, my bad then. sorry. I thought the numbers were just a list, not parts of the data to better denote the change in order. All the drama seems a little silly now ;D. It is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 5):

You realize, I presume, that your schema just about eliminates any usefulness of indexes for these kinds of queries?

A big problem is your "LIKE '%spa%'". Any "LIKE" key starting with a wildcard is an automatic table scan.

---

EDIT:
I read your question to say that there is a single field, Name, with field values something like "1 Space Company", "2 Spa resort", etc. with a number followed by words. And you needed the wild card in front of your search key to get past the number part. (This is to clarify my first comment.) Am I guessing correctly or not?

Comment: One field value for "1 Space Company"? Why aren't these two fields - "1" and "Space Company"? It's impossible to create an index on just the name part, and it's apparently really two different data elements, or you wouldn't be asking about sorting on a partial field.

Comment: A big problem is your "LIKE '%spa%'". Any "LIKE" key starting with a wildcard is an automatic table scan.

Comment: I'm not sure CHARINDEX('spa ', Name) > 0 would be better. Just because it's a table scan doens't mean it's wrong. I figured this was a search type query anyways and 'Spa' would really be a @FindMe parameter. How about trying to be helpful instead of smarmy?

Comment: He is being helpful teaching that the technique used and the underlying design is bad. Basing your search on a query like this is like building your home foundation on Jello.

Comment: I disagree. A scan type query is ok sometimes as long it has a narrow focus and isn't the primary means of searching. Oh ya, plus - he's wrong.

Comment: Bit late but this is nonsense. If the need is to find something inside a field it's unavoidable

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the necessary, but it's inefficient, doing two full table selects and it also relies on your exact match being delimited by spaces. I think FullText indexing would help, but that has overheads of its own.

```
select distinct * from
(
Select * from TableName 
   where CHARINDEX('spa ', Name) > 0
   or CHARINDEX(' spa', Name) > 0
Union
Select * from TableName 
  where Name Like '%spa%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off the top example, at least in MSSQL2005 changing the CLUSTERED to NONCLUSTERED will make it do a table scan.  CLUSTERED gives you an index seek. Looks like it matches the conditions of the question.

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest(ID INT, colname VARCHAR(20) )
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX tstidx1_tblTest ON tblTest(colname);
INSERT tblTest SELECT 1,'Space Company'
INSERT tblTest SELECT 2,'Spa Resort'
INSERT tblTest SELECT 3,'Spa Hotel'
INSERT tblTest SELECT 4,'Spare Parts'
INSERT tblTest SELECT 5,'WithoutTheKeyword'

SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE colname LIKE 'Spa%'
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(colname,'Spa') DESC;

DROP TABLE tblTest
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to define (precisely) what your ranking function really is. What if you have a row that is "The Spa." or "spa.com"? Once you have that defined, you need to put that logic into your ORDER BY clause. For example:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    Some_Table
WHERE
    name LIKE '%spa%'
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN name LIKE '% ' + @search_word + ' %' THEN 1   -- Notice the spaces
        ELSE 2
    END,
    name
```

Alternatively, you could write a ranking function and use that:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    Some_Table
WHERE
    name LIKE '%' + @search_word + '%'
ORDER BY
    dbo.GetNameMatchRank(name, @search_word)
```

Performance on very large result sets may not be too great, so this approach depends on your expected search result sizes.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
Select * from TableName where Name Like '%spa%'
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: the problem is that he want to sort by the quality of the match, not so much the matching. Order by name won't do what he wants.