# Name similar to the name that is provided by the user

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i have a table person and i want a query which give me a reports with persons whose name is similar to the name that is provided by the user.As far i have done this. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
 SELECT * FROM Person  WHERE name LIKE '%something%';
```

Comment: You can use a full text index.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931046/sounds-like-did-you-mean-that-functionality-using-full-text-search-in-sql-s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299996/find-sql-records-containing-similar-strings

Comment: The real key is you need to define "similar".

Answer (score 0):

You want to use SOUNDEX instead of LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM Person  WHERE SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('something');
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Just have to keep in mind SOUNDEX doesn't work if two names are smiliar, but first letter is different.  Example:  Casey vs. Kacey.

Comment: Good point, SOUNDEX certainly has its caviats. But it's still the closest to what the OP is asking for, in my understanding